# Lambda function timed out when trying to write data to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I´m trying to write a lambda function to insert a new User into my DynamoDB table `Users`

The table has `UserId` as index

¿Why this code doesn´t work?

```js
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uuid = require('uuid')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    
    const params = {
        User: {
            "UserId":uuid.v1(),
            "username":event.username
        },
        TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME
    }
    docClient.put(params, function(err,data){
        callback(err, data)
    })
  
};
```

My lambda test is simply:

```
{
  "username": "Javierito"
}
```

This test fails returning:

> Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

- I´ve tried inserting manually the UserId in the test
- The lambda function already has the *AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess* permission
- I have succesfully put the table name in the environmental variables of the lambda function
- I have checked also that the region of the db is correct

Comment: Is the Lambda function running inside a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB No, without VPC

Comment: Hi there, just solved it trying with another code. Still I would appreciate if anyone knows why the above code doesn´t work. I had to delete uuiv too

Comment: Shouldn't your item attribute be named `params.Item` rather than `params.User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem here is that the `uuid` module cannot be loaded. It's not available in the default Lambda runtime environment. The failure to load this module takes more than 3 seconds and hence your Lambda function times out (because you are using the 3 second default). You can include additional modules like `uuid` in your deployment upload, or use Lambda Layers.

If you increase the Lambda timeout to 30 seconds, you will see it fail with:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'"
```

Also, unrelated, your `params` object is incorrect. The property within it should be named `Item`, not `User`.